# Why omitted flavor can not be inferred automatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

While trying to run `gradle`'s `assemble` task for specific build variants, I've noticed some weird thing. Consider next configuration:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavorDimensions "shape", "color"
        rect {
            dimension "shape"
        }
        circle {
            dimension "shape"
        }
        red {
            dimension "color"
        }
        green {
            dimension "color"
        }
    }
}
```

In such case build system recognizes tasks like `assembleRect`, `assembleRectRed`, `assembleRectRedRelease`.

But when I ask for `assembleRectRelease` it claims that there is no such task. IMO it is pretty clear that I want to assemble `RectRedRelease` and `RectGreenRelease` artifacts, isn't it?

Does anybody know what is the reasons of such behavior? Or maybe there are some build system limitations?

P.S. This is related at least to gradle plugin version 2.1.0.